# Sending Ctrl+C and copying selected text from any program(chrome, adobe reader, iexplorer, notepad, word etc.)

Tags: c#, copy, ctrl, generated, selectedtext

I'm trying to copy selected text from any program(chrome, adobe reader, iexplorer, notepad, word etc.) using c#.

I have read the tutorial on how to use Microsoft UI Automation ( AutomationElement' class) but it doesn't work on any program.

I truly believe using GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent' method for generating Ctrl+C signal could work, but i could not find any example of code of using that method.

Any help will be blessed!

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in the following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

**Hope it will helps**